# How to Save related data in custom lists

Tags: 2013, custom-list, 2016

I suppose to create 3 custom lists and each one has parent and child relationship, the first list has some columns example:
departmentID,departmentName;

Second list has: employeeID,employeeName,DpeartmentID

The third list has salary:salaryid,employeeid, salary

Here I want to create a common data entry farm and save data in three lists, for this requirement how can I design the lists and relations between the lists.

Here I want to create a service catalog for our company for this can I use product catalog site collection?

Comment: Please refer to my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. I Don't know all your requirements, but I guess Creating two lists will solve your problem. One list for Departments and one list for employees(which will have lookup from departments list).
2. And if you want to create three lists. Departments, Employees, SalaryInformation. Employees list will have lookup from departments list and SalaryInformation list will have lookup from Employees List.
3. Create one page and add custom html form on the page having fields for all lists information.
4. For saving data in list you will need custom coding(I will prefer REST) in which first of all add the data in departments lists.
5. In the success of first REST call, you will get the ID of departments list item, then add data in employees list.
6. Same way in success of adding data in employees list, add data in SalaryInformation list using REST.
7. to achieve this you can use the promise pattern for asynchronous calls.

Comment: Hi there is another way to save data in 3 lists without writing custom code i mean out of the box

Comment: I am not able to add all the code to achieve this right now. But I think after reading this answer you will get the idea how you can do it.

Comment: No, you cannot do all this by OOTB solution. You will need custom coding for sure.

Comment: you have any examples in this

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to implement this is by using a Workflow, triggered by the first list, to insert data from that entry into another list.

This can be easily built using SharePoint Designer.

1. Save the data using the OOTB SharePoint's NewForm.aspx into a list such that all the basic info. is saved.
2. Trigger a workflow on item created into that list, and create item into respective list based on the ID of current data.
3. In this way, you will be able to manage data of Department, Employee and Salary into different lists without writing a code.

Comment: I have one query on this. If I do this by workflow, how can i assign the lookup from Employees List to the SalaryInformation list.?

Comment: You don't have to lookup. 
All you need to do is save the data based on the unique id from Departments list to employeeID into the Employee list and salaryID into the Salary list